# Angle trisection and perimeter of inscribed quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

I am having trouble solving the following highschool textbook exercise:

Let $AM$ and $AN$ be two chords in a circle of radius $r$ having the same length and such that the sine of the acute angle $\widehat{MAN}$ is $11/16$.
Divide the arc $MN$ not containing $A$ in three smaller arcs of the same length, $MP,PQ,QM$. Find the perimeter of the quadrilateral $MNQP$. (According to the book the solution is $23/8 r$).

I tried computing the length of the segment $MP$, but that requires a formula for $\sin(x/3)$.

Comment: what are sine and cosine for the central angle  that meets M and N,  if you call the center C  it could be MCN.

Comment: can you elaborate on how finding angle $MCN$ helps solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula $$\sin 3x=3 \sin x -4 \sin^3 x$$
will give a straight forward solution.

$$\sin 3x=\frac{11}{16} $$
$$\implies 3 \sin x -4 \sin^3 x=\frac{11}{16}$$
$$\implies 64 \sin^3x-48\sin x +11=0$$
$$\implies (4 \sin x -1)(16 \sin^2 x +4 \sin x -11)=0$$
$$\implies \sin x = \frac{1}{4}$$

(Note that other solutions for $\sin x$ are rejected because $3x$ has to be an acute angle.)
[image]

In the figure, $$\frac{MN}{\sin 3x}= 2r  $$

$$\implies MN=2r \times \sin 3x$$
$$\implies MN= 2r \times \frac{11}{16} $$
$$\implies MN= \frac{11r}{8} $$

In $\Delta MNQ$,
$$\frac{NQ}{\sin x}=\frac{MN}{\sin (180^\text{0}-3x)}$$
$$\implies NQ= \sin x \times \frac{MN}{\sin 3x}$$
$$\implies NQ= \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{\frac{11r}{8}}{\frac{11}{16}}$$
$$\implies NQ=\frac{r}{2}$$

Therefore the perimeter of $MNQP$ is

$$MN+3NQ=\frac{11r}{8}+3 \times \frac{r}{2}=\frac{23r}{8}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping for a solution which avoids solving the third-order equation, since it seems too advanced for an highschool-level exercise.